# I Can't reset apache. (Linux)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I tried to install an ssl certificate, I follow an aws "[link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#ssl_prereq)" tutorial, when I try to restart the apache server the console shows me the error: **Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

use command `apachectl configtest` the console shows me the error: **SSLCertificateKeyFile: file '/etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key' does not exist or is empty**

After following the steps in the tutorial my page no longer works because I did not finish installing the ssl certificate. How could I solve it or return the configuration prior to the change?

Comment: Fix the error identified by the configtest.  Remove the directive, or create that file (and give it some contents).

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Try this as your ***default*** configuration file and **restart** apache. If required, modify the Document Root to your actual file serving location.